# Is a lens with a focal point that doesn't shift as sun shines from different angles possible?

Tags: optics, lenses

My question: Is it possible to manufacture a lens whose focal point doesn't shift in any direction during the day when the sun shines from different angles? It is understood that the focused energy will reach a maximum only if the lens is in the ideal angle to the sun, but I need to build a system that always collects the rays in one point, even if the angle is not perfect. I can cope with a lower energy as long as at least some light is focused constantly at the same spot. I do NOT want to move the lens or the setup in any way.

If it is possible:

Can you please let me know what kind of lens would be needed for this?

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps think of a more descriptive title? "Is this possible?" doesn't give a cursory reader the slightest idea what your question will be about. (Also: Welcome on P.SE!)

Comment: It is not possible using just one lens; however I know it is possible if you use multiple lenses and/or mirrors to design a system to do that. I believe I have seen similar designs too. However, this is an engineering matter. Not physics

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible.  There is a field of study called *non-imaging optics* dedicated to this kind of problem.   See this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonimaging_optics).

FWIW, I don't agree that this question belongs somewhere else.  I think it could live here, or in Engineering.  Not sure where you would get better responses in this case.